# scrollbar appears => body movements

Tags: css

The following is a pretty simple liquid code template, where I keep this layout from getting too wide on a large monitor and a min-width may be desirable to keep this layout from getting too narrow. The container surrounds all other divs giving them their percentage-based width.

```
body {
    font:  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #CCC;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1260px;
    min-width: 780px;
    background: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

When browsing on pages with only low content, the body doesn’t shrink, move or shake (because the scrollbar doesn’t appear). When browsing between the different kind of pages (low content-no scrollbar and high content-scrollbar appears) the body moves a little bit and causes the whole web site browsing, a shaking look.

How to avoid the above page movements?
I don’t want to achieve a solution by setting `overflow:scroll;` since I don’t want always displaying the scrollbars.

Any help would be much appreciated,
thanks, Mike

Comment: I dont think there is a way with only css... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031996/alternative-to-body-overflowscroll-that-will-prevent-page-jostling-wriggling/5032080#5032080

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `overflow: auto;`? It will take both the X and Y scroll bars into account separately and only show the scroll bar if necessary.

If, as @pinkgothic suggested in the comments below, you want to always show the vertical scroll bar, try `overflow-y: scroll;`.

To always hide the horizontal scrollbar, use `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: Scrollbars only conditionally appearing is exactly user1315169's problem, though. They want a solution where the layout isn't affected by the appearance of a scrollbar. :)